# Dialogue Between Jews And Persians In Jewish Tradition

Tags: history

I always wonder what people refer to when they quote things spoken between the Jews and the Persians. Does ancient Jewish doctrine include instances of dialogue between the Jews and the Persians?

Comment: Can you [edit] in some examples of this so we  can better understand to what you refer?

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally. For instance, the Talmud in Sanhedrin talks about a king Shvor who asks the Jews about their practice of burying the dead; it turns out that Zoroastrians don't.